# How to add multiple fragments using LinearLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am programming and Android App. Inside a fragment, I have a linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
```

Now want to add several fragments to the list:

```
        val fragment = SingleReportOverviewFragment("Report 1")
        childFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail_layout, fragment).commit()

        val fragment2 = SingleReportOverviewFragment("Report 2")
        childFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail_layout, fragment2).commit()

        val fragment3 = SingleReportOverviewFragment("Report 3")
        childFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail_layout, fragment3).commit()
```

The problem is that it only shows the first fragment with "Report 1". Why are the other fragments not shown? Aren't they added correctly?

Comment: You have incorrect understanding of deal with fragments. This docs will give you all the answers https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments

Comment: If you intend to create a list of elements you should use a `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks, Recycler View is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

In the case that these fragments layouts specify `android:width="match_parent"`, you may want to change the orientation of the LinearLayout from

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

and also, consider adding scrolling, especially if each fragment fills either on width or height.

Also, I have noticed you are adding the fragment to the same layout id (`R.id.detail_layout`) -> perhaps you need to specify one for each?

Could you add the layout of the parent?